# Csvsimple: Customize the method of output

Tags: csvsimple

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
H1, H2
X1, Y1
X2, Y2
X3, Y3
X4, Y4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvautotabular{test.csv}

\end{document}
```

Suppose that I want to save space. Is there way to customize the output so that it is like, say, the example below?

```
X1   Y1        X2   Y2
X3   Y3        X4   Y4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output may be organized as `tabular` where two input lines serve as one output line. The `\csvifoddrow` macro allows to insert appropriate code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
H1, H2
X1, Y1
X2, Y2
X3, Y3
X4, Y4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  column names={H1=\one,H2=\two},
  tabular=ll@{\qquad}ll,
  table head=H1 & H2 & H1 & H2\\\hline,
  late after line=\csvifoddrow{\\}{&},
  late after last line=\\\hline,
  ]%
  {test.csv}{}%
  {\one & \two}%

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]